# php- cant get result from mysql (mysqli)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm attempting to set up an API for an app project.

I've got a mysql table called 'users', which I've added a row to.

using the code:

```
// Create connection
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","user", "pass", "db");

// Check connection
if($mysqli->connect_errno){

    $result = "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    print_r( json_encode($result) );    
    return false;

}

$row = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users");
print_r( json_encode($row) );
```

I get an empty result, how come? (connection doesn't throw an error)

to be exact i get:

```
{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}
```

**EDIT:**

got the answer to ym original question, thanks!

so now using the code:

```
$row = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '".$email."'");
$result = $row->fetch_array();
print_r( json_encode($result) );
```

I get the result:

```
{"0":"test","username":"test","1":"test@test.com","email":"test@test.com","2":"test","password":"test","3":"2013-10-18 22:22:53","date_registered":"2013-10-18 22:22:53","4":"1","id":"1"}
```

where what i want is something like:

```
{"username":"test","password":"test","email":"test@test.com", ...etc }
```

how do i get that?

Comment: If you've used `mysql_*` previously.. Could you obtain results from running `mysql_query()`? I don't think so. fetch an array from the query

Comment: Don't you need to fetch the results from $row?

Comment: Edited my answer. You need to use [mysqli_fetch_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) to avoid duplicating the results with their numeric indexes.

Comment: try my answer for associative...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_query()` will return a [mysqli_result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php), you need to [fetch (as an array in this case)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) your rows before doing anything with them. Added a line:

```
// Create connection
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","user", "pass", "db");

// Check connection
if($mysqli->connect_errno){

    $result = "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    print_r( json_encode($result) );    
    return false;

}

// Get a mysql_result
$row = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users");

// Get it into an array without numeric indexes
$result = $row->fetch_assoc();

// Display the row
print_r( json_encode($result) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users");
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
print json_encode($row);   // json_encode returns a string...
```

---

Try this for your associative array:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
   $rows[] = $row;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

or you can try... `$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`